# CROSS APPLY SQL Server query on Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, hive-udf

HDP-2.5.0.0 using Ambari 2.4.0.1

The Hive table ReportSetting is as follows :

```
id int

serializedreportsetting String
```

The column 'serializedreportsetting' is an XML data type in the source SQL Server db but is converted to String during Sqoop import, this is how it looks in SQL Server :

```
<ReportSettings4 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Trigger>
  <Manual>true</Manual>
  </Trigger>
<StartTime>
    <Year>8</Year>
    <Month>1</Month>
    <Day>1</Day>
    <Hour>0</Hour>
    <Minute>0</Minute>
  </StartTime>
  <ReportPeriod>
    <Month>0</Month>
    <Day>0</Day>
    <Hour>0</Hour>
    <Minute>5</Minute>
  </ReportPeriod>
  <Theft>
    <DigitalInput>true</DigitalInput>
    <Can>false</Can>
  </Theft>
  <SequenceNo>0</SequenceNo>
</ReportSettings4>
```

In Hive table :

```
<ReportSettings4 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Trigger><Manual>true</Manual></Trigger><StartTime><Year>8</Year><Month>12</Month><Day>31</Day><Hour>23</Hour><Minute>34</Minute></StartTime><ReportPeriod><Month>0</Month><Day>0</Day><Hour>4</Hour><Minute>0</Minute></ReportPeriod><Theft><DigitalInput>false</DigitalInput><Can>false</Can></Theft><SequenceNo>3</SequenceNo></ReportSettings4>
```

The query that works fine on the SQL Server :

```
SELECT
r.VehicleId
,rs.value('(Trigger/Manual)[1]', 'bit') AS RS_Trigger_Manual, ,CAST(CONCAT(CASE WHEN rs.value('(StartTime/Year)[1]', 'int') < 10 THEN CONCAT('200',rs.value('(StartTime/Year)[1]', 'int')) ELSE CONCAT('20',rs.value('(StartTime/Year)[1]', 'int')) END,'-',rs.value('(StartTime/Month)[1]', 'int'),'-',rs.value('(StartTime/Day)[1]', 'int'),' ',rs.value('(StartTime/Hour)[1]', 'int'),':',rs.value('(StartTime/Minute)[1]', 'int'),':','00.000') AS datetime) AS RS_StartTime
,rs.value('(ReportPeriod/Month)[1]', 'int') AS RS_ReportPeriod_Month
,rs.value('(ReportPeriod/Day)[1]', 'int') AS RS_ReportPeriod_Day
,rs.value('(ReportPeriod/Hour)[1]', 'int') AS RS_ReportPeriod_Hour
,rs.value('(ReportPeriod/Minute)[1]', 'int') AS RS_ReportPeriod_Minute
,rs.value('(Theft/DigitalInput)[1]', 'bit') AS RS_Theft_DigitalInput
,rs.value('(Theft/Can)[1]', 'bit') AS RS_Theft_Can,rs.value('(SequenceNo)[1]', 'int') 

AS RS_SequenceNo FROM ReportSetting r
  CROSS APPLY SerializedReportSetting.nodes('/*') AS ReportSettings(rs)
```

I could think of/do the following :

1. To use the CROSS APPLY, I guess [lateral view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView#LanguageManualLateralView-Example) needs to be used, here I don't have the serializedreportsetting as an array, so explode() won't work. Can someone validate if I'm thinking in the right direction
2. I simply tried to get the data in serializedreportsetting as columns using the [built-in xpath udf](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF), however, I don't get any records, few trials are as follows :

   select xpath(SerializedReportSetting,'/*') from ReportSetting limit 1;

   select xpath(SerializedReportSetting,'/ReportSettings4') from ReportSetting limit 1;

   select xpath(SerializedReportSetting,'/Trigger/Manual') from ReportSetting limit 1;

**********UPDATE-1**********

I used the regexp_replace to handle the above challenge :

```
SELECT id,
  xpath_string(SerializedReportSetting,'/ReportSettings/Trigger/Manual')        AS RS_Trigger_Manual,
  xpath_string(SerializedReportSetting,'/ReportSettings/Trigger/DriveChange')   AS RS_Trigger_DriveChange
FROM
  (SELECT id,
    regexp_replace(SerializedReportSetting, 'ReportSettings+\\d','ReportSettings') AS SerializedReportSetting
  FROM reportsetting
  WHERE id IN (1701548,3185,1700231,1700232)
  ) reportsetting_regex;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [xpath](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF#LanguageManualXPathUDF-xpath) they explicitly say:

> The `xpath()` function always returns a hive array of strings. If the expression results in a non-text value (e.g., another xml node) the function will return an empty array

So you can either use: `xpath(SerializedReportSetting,'/ReportSettings4/Trigg‌​er/Manual/text()') from ReportSetting limit 1;`

Or an even better option is to use `xpath_boolean`/`xpath_int`:

> **xpath_boolean** - 
>   Returns true if the XPath expression evaluates to true, or if a matching node is found.

`xpath_boolean(SerializedReportSetting,'/ReportSettings4/Trigg‌​er/Manual') from ReportSetting limit 1;`

> **xpath_short, xpath_int, xpath_long**
>   These functions return an integer numeric value, or the value zero if no match is found, or a match is found but the value is non-numeric.
>   Mathematical operations are supported. In cases where the value overflows the return type, then the maximum value for the type is returned.

`xpath_int(SerializedReportSetting,'/ReportSettings4/ReportPeriod/Month') from ReportSetting limit 1;`

Comment: Is it possible to write a generic xpath expression that can handle 'regular expressions' because SerializedReportSetting can have ReportSettings, ReportSettings1, ReportSettings2, ReportSettings3 and ReportSettings4 ?

Comment: It's unclear from the xpath documentation whether something like `xpath_int(SerializedReportSetting,'/ReportSettings*/ReportPeriod/Month')` would work

Comment: I thought of a workaround. You could do: `xpath_int(regexp_replace(SerializedReportSetting, 'ReportSettings[^ ]*','ReportSettings'),'/ReportSettings/ReportPeriod/Month')`.that would remove the number from the xml before calling `xpath_int`

Comment: /ReportSettings* doesn't work but I used the regexp_replace to get it working

Comment: /ReportSettings* doesn't work but I used the regexp_replace to get it working, updated my question(see 'Update-1'). Can you check if , logically, it's a correct way ?

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist I think it should be 'ReportSettings\\d+'.. otherwise looks okay